# Cannot resolve method 'in(Java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)'

Tags: java

Getting below error message

```
Cannot resolve method 'in(Java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)'
```

with below code snippet, in java class say A

```
getImplicitWaitTimeout().in(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

Java class method which class A uses

```
private Duration waitForElementTimeout;


public Duration getImplicitWaitTimeout() {
        if (this.waitForElementTimeout == null) {
            int configuredWaitForTimeoutInMilliseconds = ThucydidesSystemProperty.WEBDRIVER_TIMEOUTS_IMPLICITLYWAIT.integerFrom(this.environmentVariables, (int)DefaultTimeouts.DEFAULT_IMPLICIT_WAIT_TIMEOUT.toMillis());
            this.waitForElementTimeout = Duration.ofMillis((long)configuredWaitForTimeoutInMilliseconds);
        }

        return this.waitForElementTimeout;
    }
```

Is this related to Java 8?

Comment: Is this really error message? Never heard `Java.util.concurrent.TimeOut`

Comment: posting the entire stacktrace would be helpful

Comment: If a package starts with a capital letter it's not standard and not in the JDK.

Comment: You're trying but call `in()` on a `Duration` object, but I cannot find such a method in the documentation. Did you define this method? Are you just trying to convert the `Duration` object to seconds?

Comment: My bad, updated to correct package name @Sun

Comment: @GBlodgett yes, I need to convert Duration into seconds. I think in() method is part of framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want seconds from the duration, just `get` them.  No conversion required.

```
getImplicitWaitTimeout().getSeconds();
```